# Polar coordinate plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have multiple `theta` and `rho` stored as matrices in variable `out`. I want to plot all of them using `polar` function in Matlab R2015b.

I'm new to Matlab and so far I did this :

```
subplot(1,3,1)
polar(out(1),out(2),'*')
subplot(1,3,2)
polar(out(3),out(4),'*')
subplot(1,3,3)
polar(out(5),out(6),'*')
```

[image: matlab plot image]

I've two questions:

How can I combine them into a single polar plot, i.e one figure instead of three with `'*'` position intact ?

How can I remove the lower part of polar plot so that I can have a semicircle instead of full plot? Is it possible to customize polar plot labels like removing the degree labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. - Use the commmand `hold on` (and get rid of the subplots) **or**
   - Plot everything together with `polar(out(1:2:end),out(2:2:end),'*')`
2. Use the `ylim([-0.5 0])` command see [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18457-how-to-plot-only-half-of-a-polar-plot-i-e-only-the-lower-hemisphere-from-90-270).